# Why filter through hardware?

Tags: pcb, circuit-analysis, integrated-circuit, filter, low-power

I am trying to measure a signal with a voltage amplitude between 10-100 microvolts and a frequency between 7-30Hz. The guide I am following suggests filtering out 60Hz noise using a notch filter, as well as additional LPF and HPF to focus only on this range (5 and 40 Hz), then one more notch filter at 60Hz.

Of course noise will need to be filtered out in order to see such a small signal. My  concern is, with today's computing prowess, what's the benefit of doing this through hardware? Couldn't I design a circuit to scale the voltage between two values (say -1 and 1V), such that it can be easily and safely read by a second device, then do the filtering on this second device?

As strange as it sounds, the problem I am trying to solve has bountiful resources for software, but limited ones for hardware.  Imagine an audio recorder sending data to a computer. You want the audio recorder to have a battery that lasts as long as possible, and would like to minimize the power-intensive circuit components involved in filtering. Is it a bad idea to do the filtering on the computer since it's plugged in to a wall outlet & is made to handle much larger computational tasks? I'm not trying to put electrical engineers out of a job; I have a real world use case for this scenario!

In short, is a purely software filtering approach valid for a signal like this? What about other signals? In general, with regard to modern technology, why do we *ever* filter using hardware?

Comment: First development in electronics(hardware) gave birth to computing(software) you just cant do everything computationally, second you cant scale everything if you amplify the signal you end up amplifying the noise also,hence you need to band limit the signal where your information is actually stored, using a filter.

Comment: A resistor and a capacitor cost somewhat less than a processor.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to at least use hardware for your anti-aliasing filter.

This means filtering out signals and noise above the Nyquist rate (1/2 of your sampling rate). You have to do this in hardware because after sampling, interference or noise in the alias bands won't be distinguishable from the signal in your desired band.

Whatever other filtering you want to do will likely be easier if you can use more oversampling. At which point you will have a trade-off: Does increasing oversampling cost you more power or does using analog filters?

Answer (score 3):

This is more of a question about signal-to-noise and inter-modulation distortion than Nyquist sampling theory. Chances are that the 60 Hz signal will be fairly significant, and over the whole band that you are sampling its likely that there will be a reasonable amount of noise power from other sources.

You will need to scale your ADC so that the worst case input voltage is still less than full scale. This probably means that your wanted signal will be just a few LSBs. The biggest problem you will face is that when one of the MSBs toggles, (127 to 128), the delta won't be exactly the same as one of the LSBs toggling (7 to 8). The result is that any larger unwanted signal will mix with your wanted signal, and spread its spectrum. This means that even once the unwanted signal is filtered out, you end up with more noise on your wanted signal.

As well as limiting the dynamic range using analogue filtering, you can also make sure your sample rate is above 120 Hz (so the line noise is not aliased), and consider using an even higher sample rate, *dithering* and decimation (this adds out-of-band noise to the signal to spread the inter-modulation wider, resulting in it being easier to reject digitally).

Its possible to do what you ask with all the filtering in the digital domain, but it will cost both in increased ADC specs, and/or DSP cycles.

Comment: The issues of MSB toggles vs LSB toggles is basically non-linearity and non-ideal characteristics of the ADC, is that right?

Comment: Yes, each bit will have some tolerance, this can be of the order of an lsb in magnitude. There is always quantisation noise of 0.5 lsb though,even with perfect steps.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the intermodulation products due to these nonlinearities. It's not something that comes up in a normal undergraduate DSP education, and not something I'd thought much about!

Answer (score 0):

In many cases such as RF systems you are working with high frequencies(order of Gbs) which ADC and DAC needed for sampling and recreating analog signal is essentially impossible with current technology as the ADC's sampling rate for example is limited by MOSFET's parasitic capacitor which are worsening in the state of the art techs. Also at lower frequencies the cost of DSP system from design to hardware costs can be much higher if your end use of hardware is only for filtering in comparison to OpAmp base filters.

Comment: The OP is talking about frequencies in 0-100Hz range, I bet he has no issues with sampling frequency.